# How to get json object/array from mysqli prepare (all matching rows) without indexes

Tags: php, json, mysqli, prepared-statement

i spent lot of hours trying to figure out the right way to output json array/object from mysql database like this :

```
expected output 
    {
        "ITEM1": 20,
        "ITEM2": 15,
        "ITEM3": 12
    }
```

As each key/value pair corresponding to one mysql table row (no need to display ID column).

```
id |item| price
```

This is my current code using `MYSQLND driver` on debian:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pswd";
$dbname = "json";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$itemInitArr = array();
$decharge = 0;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT item, price FROM stock WHERE total_sold = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $decharge);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();


                            while ($itemInit = $result->fetch_assoc())
                            {
                                $itemInitArr[] = array (
                                            $itemInit['item'] => $itemInit['price']
                                    );
                            }
$stmt->close();                         
$final_data = json_encode($itemInitArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
echo $final_data;

$conn->close();
?>
```

which output this :

```
[
    {
        "ITEM1": 20
    },
    {
        "ITEM2": 15
    },
    {
        "ITEM3": 12
    }
]
```

So, where is the mistake and how to solve it to match expected output ?

Comment: what r u doing if one item has the same name as another?

Comment: @sintakonte, 'item' is a generic name, just for posting purposes. Database is filled with verification of unique instance of 'item name' before inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the way you build your array to...

```
$itemInitArr[$itemInit['item']] =  $itemInit['price'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$idx = 1; 
while ($itemInit = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $itemInitArr['ITEM'.$idx] =  $itemInit['price'];
     $idx++;
}
$final_data = json_encode($itemInitArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

of if the ITEM1 ... ITEMN is the content fo the column item

```
     $itemInitArr[$itemInit['item']] =  $itemInit['price'];
```

Comment: Your second example of code puts all values in the element 'item'

Comment: @scaisEdge, got keys but values are null white that code. And seems there is a missing $ before 'idx++;'.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pswd";
$dbname = "json";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$itemInitArr = array();
$decharge = 0;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT item, price FROM stock WHERE total_sold = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $decharge);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();


                            while ($itemInit = $result->fetch_assoc())
                            {
                                $itemInitArr[$itemInit['item']] = $itemInit['price'];

                            }
$stmt->close();                         
$final_data = json_encode($itemInitArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
echo $final_data;

$conn->close();
?>
```